# unity: the rotation is stopped at 1 to 0.1 degrees

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I made the script and want to run the game, after the ai past that door, the door is not completely closed as you can see in this image.

[image]

when I check the inspecter it's acturlly because it didnt run the Ienumerator completely so it still has 1 to 0.1 unrotated.
It seems like it's because the stop coroutine
is triggered when the npc leaves. there is some problem with the transition.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
public class DoorScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private NavMeshObstacle Obstacle;
    public bool IsOpen = false;
    [SerializeField] private float Speed = 2f;
    [SerializeField] private float RotationAmount = 90f;
    [SerializeField] private float FowardDirection = 0f;
    private Vector3 StartRotation;
    private Vector3 Foward;
    private Coroutine AnimationCoroutine;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Obstacle = GetComponent<NavMeshObstacle>();
        Obstacle.carveOnlyStationary = false;
        Obstacle.carving = IsOpen;
        Obstacle.enabled = IsOpen;
        StartRotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        Foward = transform.right;

    }
    public void Open(Vector3 UserPosition)
    {
        if(!IsOpen)
        {
            if(AnimationCoroutine != null)
            {
                StopCoroutine(AnimationCoroutine);
            }
        }
        float dot = Vector3.Dot(Foward, (UserPosition - transform.position).normalized);
        AnimationCoroutine = StartCoroutine(DoRotationOpen(dot));
    }
    private IEnumerator DoRotationOpen(float ForwardAmount)
    {
        Quaternion startRotation = transform.rotation;
        Quaternion endRotation;
        if(ForwardAmount >= FowardDirection)
        {
            endRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(StartRotation.x, startRotation.y - RotationAmount, startRotation.z));
        }
        else
        {
            endRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(StartRotation.x, startRotation.y + RotationAmount, startRotation.z));
        }
        IsOpen = true;
        float time = 0;
        while(time < 1)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(startRotation, endRotation, time);
            yield return null;
            time += Time.deltaTime * Speed;
        }
        Obstacle.enabled = true;
        Obstacle.carving = true;
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        if(IsOpen)
        {
            if(AnimationCoroutine != null)
            {
                StopCoroutine(AnimationCoroutine);
            }
            AnimationCoroutine = StartCoroutine(DoRotationClose());
            Obstacle.carving = false;
            Obstacle.enabled = false;

        }
    }
    private IEnumerator DoRotationClose()
    {
        Obstacle.carving = false;
        Obstacle.enabled = false;
        Quaternion startRotation = transform.rotation;
        Quaternion endRotation = Quaternion.Euler(StartRotation);
        IsOpen = false;
        float time = 0;
        while(time < 1)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(startRotation, endRotation, time);
            yield return null;
            time += Time.deltaTime * Speed;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried too double check the ai door tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFHvdI08Cus
and I check unity forums and stackoverflow and there is no solution for that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved it even though it's not perfect but gamers cant really see the catch in the code.

```
    private IEnumerator DoRotationClose()
    {
        Obstacle.carving = false;
        Obstacle.enabled = false;
        Quaternion startRotation = transform.rotation;
        Quaternion endRotation = Quaternion.Euler(StartRotation);
        IsOpen = false;
        float time = 0;
        while(time < 1)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(startRotation, endRotation, time);
            yield return null;
            time += Time.deltaTime * Speed;
            transform.rotation = endRotation;
        }
    }
```

transform.rotation = endRotation; helped fixed this because it's forcing it to close completly even the time is > 1.

Comment: you would rather move the last line **after** the `while` loop

Answer (score 1):

The code is something like this:

```
while (time < 1)
{ 
    // rotate stuff
    time += Time.deltaTime * Speed;
}
```

So the `time` variable is increased to (lets say) 1.01 but the rotation code is not executed again, as the next time the `while` loop runs (in this Coroutine) time will already be >= 1.

Solution: move the rotation code below code that modifies time.
That way, we can ensure that the end-rotation is reached (because the Lerp will go to 100% of endRotation when passing 1)